# WSDL error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't bind to service

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://localhost:8888/testes/wsdl/calculadora.wsdl">
    <message name="requisicaoSoma">
        <part name="x" type="xsd:int" />
        <part name="y" type="xsd:int" />
    </message>
    <message name="respostaSoma">
        <part name="z" type="xsd:int" />
    </message>
    <portType name="calculadoraPortType">
        <operation name="soma">
            <input message="requisicaoSoma" />
            <output message="respostaSoma" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="calculadoraBinding" type="tns:calculadoraPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation>
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost:8888/testes/calculadora.php" />
            <input><soap:body use="literal" /></input>
            <output><soap:body use="literal" /></output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
</definitions>
```

Am I missing something?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have not defined the service element of the WSDL. For more information refer to the below links.

[WSDL Essentials](http://oreilly.com/catalog/webservess/chapter/ch06.html)

[Sample WSDL](http://www.w3.org/2001/04/wsws-proceedings/uche/wsdl.html)

Comment: First link is 404

Answer (score 0):

A correct wsdl would look like seen below.

Pay attention to

- definition of a name at the top
- service section at the bottom (assumed url of service - up to webserver config)

```
<definitions
    name="calculadora"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tns="http://localhost:8888/testes/wsdl/calculadora.wsdl">
    <message name="requisicaoSoma">
        <part name="x" type="xsd:int" />
        <part name="y" type="xsd:int" />
    </message>
    <message name="respostaSoma">
        <part name="z" type="xsd:int" />
    </message>
    <portType name="calculadoraPortType">
        <operation name="soma">
            <input message="requisicaoSoma" />
            <output message="respostaSoma" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="calculadoraBinding" type="tns:calculadoraPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation>
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost:8888/testes/calculadora.php" />
            <input><soap:body use="literal" /></input>
            <output><soap:body use="literal" /></output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    
    <wsdl:service name="CalculadoraService">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:calculadoraPortType" name="calculadoraBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8888/CalculadoraService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</definitions>
```